# Session::instance() after session_start - Kohana (v.3.2)

Tags: php, session, exception, kohana

I'm using Kohana's Session class without problems, but now I'm facing a special situation.
In my script I have to load a vendor class, which somewhere is calling `session_start`.

Later in the code I need to call Session::instance(), and this is resulting in a `Error reading session data.` exception.

I can't modify the vendor code (just to be concrete it is the facebook php sdk, and I don't want to modify it), and I have to call `Session::instance()` later.

How to solve this situation?

You have to know, that a simple

```
<?php
session_start();
Session::instance();
?>
```

will produce the same exception.
I think this is a bug in Kohana 3.2, but I need to trick it some way.

To learn more about the `Session` class, check this out: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Session

Btw, I'm using the default, native session class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Alex Mihai pointed out, we can use the session id parameter in Session::instance() to restart it.

The exception you get is that the session is still running and you cannot restore a running session. So you have to close it first.

Try this:

```
// Start session
session_start();    

// Store session id and close the session
$sessionId = session_id();
session_write_close();

// Then we can restore the session by using the session id 
// and the Session class from Kohana
Session::Instance(Session::$default, $sessionId);
```

It might also not be the most elegant solution, but this worked for me and I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest I don't think a "better" solution exists, this is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The Kahana doc mentions for Session::instance():

> Some session types (native, database) also support restarting a
>   session by passing a session id as the second parameter.

Maybe you could try passion session_id() to Session::instance() as the second param.

Comment: Good idea. This was one of my first attempts to solve to trick this, but sadly it's not working.

`session_start(); Session::instance(Session::$default, session_id());` produces the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I'm started using, but I don't accept this anser right now, because maybe a better solution will come from others.

So, to avoid these kind of exceptions, without modifying the source code of the `Session` class, I have to make sure that the session is always started with the `Session` class.
In my case I just call `Session::instance()`, before `require`-ing the vendor classes.
Maybe not the most elegant, but it works.
If you have any better idea, solution (I hope so) I'm all ears :)