# How to get session variable resides outside kohana inside application?

Tags: php, session, model-view-controller, kohana, kohana-3

I have a page that resides outside of Kohana that has some session variables, and I have another page inside Kohana that wants to use those session variables. But i am not able to get those session variables using kohana session instance. Is it possible to get those session variables from inside Kohana? If yes, what configuration settings do I need to change. Help from you is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have answered a nearly similar question before and the trick is to convert the session info into a Kohana Session object.

Check my answer at this question: [Session::instance() after session_start - Kohana (v.3.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836423/sessioninstance-after-session-start-kohana-v-3-2/13843178#13843178)